# If $n=2m$, what is the order of the permutation $\sigma(k)=2k , \quad \sigma(m+k)=2k-1$

Tags: finite-groups, permutations, permutation-groups

Let $n=2m$.  What is the order of the following permutation $\sigma$?

$$1\leq k\leq m  \Rightarrow   \sigma(k)=2k , \quad \sigma(m+k)=2k-1$$

Comment: Could you share your data for small $m$?

Comment: There is only one guess:  if $n=2^m$ then $|\sigma|=2^m$ (have no clear proof yet!)

Comment: If one may check by computer, a mysterious irregularity is observed for different cases $n$

Comment: Aside from a [guess](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441064/if-n-2m-what-is-the-order-of-the-permutation-sigmak-2k-quad-sigmamk#comment1137747_441064), presumably you have gathered data on specific values of small $m$.  (If not, then that's where you should start!)  What [irregularity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441064/if-n-2m-what-is-the-order-of-the-permutation-sigmak-2k-quad-sigmamk#comment1137748_441064) have you observed?

Comment: @ABB is not $|\sigma|=2m$ for $n=2^m$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By adding a fixed point at $0$ (which preserves the order), the permutation $\sigma$ considered is just the multiplication by $2$ modulo $2m+1$. Thus, for $k \ge 0$, $\sigma^k$ is the identity map if and only if it fixes $1$, namely if and only if $2m+1$ divides $2^k-1$.

Hence, the order of $\sigma$ is the order of $2$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/(2m+1)\mathbb{Z})^\times$. I do not think that there are formulas for this, although the order necessarily divides $\phi(2m+1)$ by Lagrange theorem.

Comment: I wonder if this was what OP was actually interested in, but ABB reformulated it to a permutation type question..

Comment: @Per Alexandersson, Yes, you are right. If this problem could be figured out, then probably one may find an approach to compute the   eigenvalues/eigenvectors of some non-symmetric discrete trigonometric transforms which are coming from signal processing in electrical engineering!

Comment: In more detail, this reduces to the case when $2m+1$ is a prime $p$, since the order of $2$ modulo $p^\nu$ is $p^{\nu-1}$ times the order of $2$ modulo $p$, while the order of $2$ modulo $mn$ for $m$, $n$ coprime is the lcm of orders modulo $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Is it easy to prove that the order of 2 modulo $p^\nu$ is $p^{\nu-1}$ times the order of 2 modulo $p$? I am a bit surprised by this statement.

Comment: Sorry, this is not actually true. The smallest counterexample I found is this: order of $2$ modulo $1093$ is the same as order of $2$ modulo $1093^2$, namely $364$. For a proof that once the order of some $1<a<p$ modulo $p^k$ is divisible by $p$ then order of $a$ modulo $p^{k+1}$ is $p$ times order of $a$ modulo $p^k$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2217138/214353 It seems also true that these orders remain the same before becoming divisible by $p$. The smallest example when order modulo $p^3$ is not divisible by $p$ seems to be $p=113$, $a=68$.

Comment: Namely, orders of $68$ modulo $113$, $113^2$ and $113^3$ are all equal to $112$.